# HashTable not outputting correct data

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm having problems with my `HashTable`. While the code compiles and runs just fine, I'm not getting the output I desire.

The `final HashTable` should have a table size 10; Sue(453) and Bobby(170) should be in index 1, Robert(348) in index 2, Mark(231) in 3 and George(15) in 6. Instead when I run my program, my `HashTable` looks completely different as it has a size of 22 and Bobby has two values(one should have been removed) so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

I have a suspicion that I messed up in the `"put"` method, but I can't wrap my head around what could be the issue there and why the comparison is failing when trying to remove the first Bobby value instead of adding it on top of the old value.

```
public class HashTable <K, V>
{
   private HashItem[] table;
   private int count;
   private double loadFactor;

   private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 5;
   private static final double DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75;

private class HashItem <K, V>
{
   private int hash;
   private K key;
   private V value;
   private HashItem <K, V> next;

   public HashItem(int hashIn, K keyIn, V valueIn, HashItem<K, V> nextIn)
   {
    hash = hashIn;
    key = keyIn;
    value = valueIn;
    next = nextIn;
    }
}

public HashTable(int initialCapacity, double loadFactorIn)
{
   if(initialCapacity <= 0)
   {
   throw new  
            IllegalArgumentException("Capacity must be > 0.");
   }
   if(loadFactorIn < 0)
   {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Load factor must be > 0.");
   }
   loadFactor = loadFactorIn;
   table = new HashItem[initialCapacity];
}

public HashTable()
{
   this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR);
}

public int size()
{
   return count;
}

private void rehash()
{
   HashItem[] oldTable = table;

   //create new table
   int capacity = oldTable.length * 2 + 1;
   table = new HashItem[capacity];

   //get elements at each old table index
   for(int i = 0; i< oldTable.length; i++)
   {
      HashItem<K, V> item = oldTable[i];
      //add the element from old table and its linked elements
      while(item != null)
      {
      put(item.key, item.value);
      item = item.next;
      }
   }
}

public V put(K keyIn, V valueIn)
{
   if (valueIn == null)
   {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value cannot be null");
   }

   int hash = Math.abs(keyIn.hashCode());
   int index = hash % table.length;

   // get hash item at target location(if any)
   HashItem<K , V> current = table[index];
   // iterate through linked nodes at the location (if any)
   while(current != null)
   {
      //if an item with the same hash & key is there, replace
      if(hash == current.hash && current.key.equals(current.hash))
      {
       V oldItem = current.value;
       current.value = valueIn;
       return oldItem;
      }
     current = current.next;
   }      

   int threshold = (int) (table.length * loadFactor);
   if(size() >= threshold)
   {
      rehash();
      index = hash % table.length;
   }

   current = table[index];
   table[index] = new HashItem <K, V>(hash, keyIn, valueIn, current);
   count++;

   return valueIn;
}

public V get(Object keyIn)
{
   int hash = Math.abs(keyIn.hashCode());
   int index = hash % table.length;

   HashItem<K, V> item = table[index];
   while(item != null)
   {
      if(hash == item.hash && item.key.equals(keyIn))
      {
         return item.value;
      }
      item = item.next;
   }   
return null;
}

public boolean remove(Object keyIn)
 {
   int hash = Math.abs(keyIn.hashCode());
   int index = hash % table.length;

   HashItem<K, V> item = table[index];
   HashItem<K, V> previous = null;
   while(item != null)
   {
      if(item.key.equals(keyIn))
      {
      //if it is not in root node, replace links
         if(previous != null)
         {
            previous.next = item.next;
         }  
      //if it was the root, move next item in the chain down
      else{
            table[index] = item.next;
          }
      count--;
      return true;
   }        
   previous = item;
   item = item.next;
   } 
  return false;
 }

 public void makeEmpty()
   {
      table = new HashItem[table.length];
      count = 0;
   }  

public static void main(String [] args)
 {
   HashTable<String, Integer> purchases = new HashTable <String, Integer>();

   String names[] = {"Yuan", "Bobby", "Kevin"};

   purchases.put(names[0], 654);
   purchases.put(names[1], 341);
   purchases.put(names[2], 70);

   purchases.put(names[1], 170);

   System.out.println("Yuan: " + purchases.get(names[0]));
   System.out.println("Bobby: " + purchases.get(names[1]));
   System.out.println("Kevin: " + purchases.get(names[2]));

   purchases.remove(names[0]);
   purchases.remove(names[2]);

   purchases.put("Robert" , 348);
   purchases.put("Sue", 453);
   purchases.put("Mark", 231);
   purchases.put("George", 15);
 }    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skimmed through your code. The Problem seems to be with you Rehash method. when you invoke put again inside rehash().. the put method does not know if the invocation came from the user as an insert or a rehash. the count variable will increment even if rehashing  is invoked which is not correct.

Kindle use a Debugger to help yourself with other problems. a quick google search on debugging a program will help.

EDIT: Inside put method current.key.equals(current.hash) shouldn't this comparison be more like 
current.key.equals(keyIn).. the original probably will never be true and this is why the replace does not work.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, changing `current.hash` to `keyIn` seems to have done the trick. I seem to have gotten confused as I thought that we were comparing the key with the hash to see if they were equals so I figured `current.hash` was the only thing that would've worked.